# I am slightly confused here in the IF statement what is this term called? How can you create a variable directly in the parameter?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between this:

[image: Difference between first image]

and this:

[image: Second image]

How is it returning different results despite both being created objects?

I am confused here so I was just taking a look at some sample code and saw this. Inside the `if` statement it says `Ball ball`? So it's checking to see if area is type `Ball`. But that `ball` variable inside the parameter how is it any different to say if I were to for example only leave the if statement as

```
if (area is Ball) { ball.Reset(); }
```

As opposed to

```
if (area is Ball ball) { ball.Reset(); }
```

Because these 2 returned different results: the first one without the ball var inside of the parameter just broke the game. The second one didn't cause any issues.

What I am asking is what is the difference between both why use one other the over?`

And what topic does this relate to in C# by this I mean to say if I asked you what is this `[Obsolete]` tag in C# related to you would say attributes. So for the

```
if(area is Ball ball) { ball.Reset(); }
```

what is this related to in topics of C# when you can create a var inside a parameter whilst comparing and also apparently it giving different results to the other one.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns

Comment: OMG thank you so much just checked now exactly what I was looking for <3.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
if(area is Ball x)
```

Means "if area is of type Ball, make a variable of type Ball called x, cast area to type Ball and assign it to x"

I renamed it to help clear up some confusion you seem to have when you say you tried this and it didn't work:

```
if(area is Ball){
  Ball.Reset();
```

`Ball` is a type, the name of a class. It isn't any particular instance of a Ball. `ball` with a lowercase b, in your original code `is Ball ball` is an instance of a Ball; `ball` is some particular Ball with a certain radius or whatever. If you have a method Reset that is not marked as `static` then you have to call it on an instance of a ball

```
ball.Reset(); //your code, works ok
x.Reset();    //my code, works ok
Ball.Reset(); //error "an object reference is required for the non-static..."
```

So; case is important in `Ball ball` - pay close attention to it

---

Going back to

```
if(area is Ball x){
    x.Reset();
```

In the old days we would maybe have written this as:

```
Ball x;
if(area is Ball){
    x = area as Ball;
    x.Reset();
```

which can be read as `if area is` a `Ball`, then we know we can safely cast it `as` a `Ball` and capture the result of the cast into `x` so we can use it many times without casting

Often C# evolves to find more compact ways of writing things

Here's another example of a different process. In the old days we might have written:

```
if(area != null && area.Thing != null && area.Thing.OtherThing != null && area.Thing.OtherThing.WhatWeWant == "")
```

That's a lot of null checking to make sure we don't get a NullRef exception, just to get access to the one buried property we want. Nowadays we can use a much more compact syntax:

```
if(area?.Thing?.OtherThing?.WhatWeWant == "")
```

That `?.` gives up digging down through the properties in the chain as soon as one of them turns out to be `null`. For example if `Thing` was null it wouldn't even try to access `OtherThing`, it would just stop and resolve the whole thing in the left side of the `==` as `null` which means we can avoid getting a null reference exception. If anything along the way is `null` the comparison either becomes `if(null == "")` which is `false`. It's a much more succinct way of achieving the same as checking everything for null before trying to access it.

---

That feature of being able to specify a variable name after `is` makes code a lot more compact and readable - you just have to remember it's the equivalent of the old form, even if it makes it possible to write code that looks a little weird:

```
if(area is Ball x){
    x.Reset();
}
x = new Ball();
```

The new syntax looks like `x` was declared inside the `if`, so why is it accessible outside?

Remember the old syntax:

```
Ball x;
if(...){
}
x = new Ball();
```

and it makes more sense

Comment: Before C# 7, I belive the recommended way to cast was `Ball b = area as Ball` and then check the `b` against `null`. This does type check only once, whereas `is` + `as` does it twice

Comment: Sure, but I picked a way that was closely correlatable to the syntax the OP used that they were confused with, in order to explain the point, hence the use of the phrase "would maybe have"